# Linux screen: Clearing Screen List

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Though I have the feeling the answer might be already out there, after reading several questions I did not manage to solve my problem. Apologies in advance in case of duplication.

**Current Situation**: I have 1 screen detached I cannot manage to take control of:

```
There is a screen on:
        9667.pts-11.compute-2-1 (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-pan.
```

Whenever I do `screen -r, -R, -d -r, -D -RR`, the ssh session gets stuck and not responsive.

**Question**: I am looking for a method to clear the screen list (I am not particularly interested in recovering that screen).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: To complete the case: Now I started a new screen and I have two screens in the list. I can attach and detach the new screen without any problem. However, the old screen (the one in the question) is still not accessible.

Comment: The system gets stuck and you have to reboot?  That sounds like a hardware / driver problem.  No matter how badly confused `screen` is, you should be able to kill it from another ssh session, or local terminal window / text console.

Comment: Maybe my explanation was not completely correct and descriptive. What actually happened was: 1) I connected to the machine through an ssh session, 2) I tried to recover the detached screen session through 'screen -r' or the like (see the question) 3) the ssh session became not responsive to command line instructions and keyboard shortcuts such as 'CTRL-c' or 'CTRL-x', 4) I closed the ssh session and started a new one to take control of the machine again. I edited the question to remove "reboot"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of this `screen` session , you can do:

`kill 9667; screen -wipe`